# How to handle null value in a method from which a null returning method is called?

Tags: java, null

This is the sample code piece

```
public OperationResult beforeEverything(BDDObject savingObject) {

  String checkAssetRole = doCheckAssetRole(savingObject);

  if (checkAssetRole != null && !checkAssetRole.equals("MissingAssetRole")) {
    return new OperationResult(new OperationExecutionError("SIP-37006",
                               new String[] {"Duplicate asset roles have been defined: " + checkAssetRole},
                               getLocalizationGate()));
  }
  ArrayList<String> warnings = new ArrayList<String>();
  boolean showWarning = false;

  if (checkAssetRole != null && checkAssetRole.equals("MissingAssetRole")) {
    mLogger.debug("Warning  of Asset role");
    warnings.add(new String(
                "Asset role is missing. Do you want to save the record?"));
    showWarning = true;
  }
  return OperationResult.OK;
}
```

The thing is that `doCheckAssetRole` method returns `null`. So how can I handle it in `beforeEverything()` method. Is there some exception handling to be done? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Put a `null` check and then throw a `RuntimeException` with `message` .

```
 if(checkAssetRole==null)
      throw new RuntimeException ("AssetRole value is NULL.");
```

And your code look like this.

```
String checkAssetRole = doCheckAssetRole(savingObject);

if(checkAssetRole==null)
      throw new RuntimeException ("AssetRole value is NULL.");

if (checkAssetRole != null && !checkAssetRole.equals("MissingAssetRole")) {
return new OperationResult(new OperationExecutionError("SIP-37006",
                           new String[] {"Duplicate asset roles have been defined: " + checkAssetRole},
                           getLocalizationGate()));
}
```

Comment: I think `IllegalArgumentException` is better than `RuntimeException` in that case (more specific).

Comment: 1. you should also remove the null check in the following if-conditions too because they aren't necessary any more. 2. I think IllegalArgumentException isn't more specific - after all the error is not because of an illegal argument. 3. If you just remove the null checks for checkAssetRole altogether, you would get an NullPointerException - now that's what I call specific.

Comment: @Axel : As per the code posted by OP null checks are already there in all if block so he won't get NullPointerException.

Comment: This is a good answer. Can u pls tell me whether I have to handle the RuntimeException after throwing it? I mean, a try-catch block is necessary, right?

Comment: @amicngh: Yes, that's why I suggested removing the null checks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want is your business logic if doCheckAssetRole is null:

- it corresponds to a valid business use case, so you have a corresponding OperationResult object to return for this case, so you would do something like

  ```
  if (checkAssetRole == null)
    return new NoAssetRoleOperationResult();
  ```

  And the calling code will handle this kind of result.
- its never supposed to happen, except if the user made a mistake, then you throw a checked exception.

  ```
  if (checkAssetRole == null)
    throw new NoAssetRoleException(yourMessage);
  ```

  and you make your method declaration `throws NoAssetRoleExeption`. The calling code is then responsible of forwarding this error back to the user.
- it failed because of a environment error (a remote server is down), you throw an unchecked exception like `RuntimeException`, an top level code will catch it to indicate there is an environment failure.
- it failed because of a development error (theorically this code should never return null), then you assert:

  ```
  assert checkAssetRole != null : "assetRole should not be null"
  ```

Pick your case :)

Comment: In your first case, `return new NoAssetRoleOperationResult();` the `NoAssetRoleOperationResult()` needs to be cast to the desired object type.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `null` from a method is normal practice. The caller needs to check for it.
In your case you can just do a check and act accordingly. If you want to throw and Exception, then you can do so.

```
   public OperationResult beforeEverything(BDDObject savingObject) {

     String checkAssetRole = doCheckAssetRole(savingObject);

     if (checkAssetRole == null) {
         // DO SOMETHING HERE. eg. throw new RuntimeException("Asset Role should not be null");
         //   or simply return null;

     }
```

Comment: Can u pls tell me whether I have to handle the RuntimeException after throwing it? I mean, a try-catch block is necessary, right?

Comment: Runtime exceptions do not require a try/catch block.
If you are building a web-app you need to decide what to do with that error. You can create your own exception class (sub-class RuntimeException) and then catch it further down and display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do when null is returned. If you want to return a value NotOK when null is returned from doCheckAssetRole, then you can use this fragment.

```
public OperationResult beforeEverything(BDDObject savingObject) {

  String checkAssetRole = doCheckAssetRole(savingObject);

  if (checkAssetRole == null) {
    return OperationResult.NotOK; // Or something else that indicates to the calling method what happened.
  else {
    if (!checkAssetRole.equals("MissingAssetRole")) {
      return new OperationResult(new OperationExecutionError("SIP-37006",
                                 new String[] {"Duplicate asset roles have been defined: " + checkAssetRole},
                                 getLocalizationGate()));
    }
    ArrayList<String> warnings = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean showWarning = false;

    if (checkAssetRole.equals("MissingAssetRole")) {
      mLogger.debug("Warning  of Asset role");
      warnings.add(new String(
                   "Asset role is missing. Do you want to save the record?"));
      showWarning = true;
    }
    return OperationResult.OK;
  }
}
```